# Use models in angular to get data from rest api

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

My api return data like this:

```
public class ApiResult
{
public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
public ApiResultStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
public string Message { get; set; }
public TData Data { get; set; }
}
```

That status code is enum (0,1,2 ...)
And data is returned dto like (car, user , ...) that can be null if error occur or list<> or single dto

I write this models in angular to get them:

```js
export class Api<T> {
  isSuccess: boolean;
  statusCode: number;
  message: string;
  data: T;
}

//***

interface IBase<T> {
  id: T;
}

abstract class Base implements IBase<number> {
  id: number;
}

//***

export class User extends Base {
  public token: string;
  public roles: Role[];
  public Email: string;
  public FullName: string;
  public PhoneNumber: string;
}
```

And I want to get for example user or list of user like this:

```
.get<Api<User>>()...
.get<Api<User[]>>()...
```

My question is that this way is good to create model?
If yes am I use it correct in last code (get<>...) ?

Comment: What does USE look like?  Also the result either worked or failed. You only need issucess, status code and message when http fails. Not for every result

Comment: @JohnPeters All of rest api return data like code that I send, my question is that am I use (export, abstract,interface) in write way?